# Evernote import txt

Tags: evernote

I have a lot of food thoughts in txt. I want them in evernote.

I tried to Right click the file and the use send to evernote [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/974ukr0i5c189r7/Screenshot%202014-07-10%2016.18.20.png) but it ended up with

- wrong title, it kept the first line of my text file and not the name of the text file
- unicode errors

see my [example note](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pi0naleuwrylfyp/Screenshot%202014-07-10%2016.18.45.png)

I have googled "import evernote txt" and found three threads

1. https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/31369-how-could-i-import-a-folder-with-huge-number-txt-files-and-make-the-txt-file-name-as-the-note-title/
2. https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/23577-how-to-import-notes-to-evernote/
3. https://discussion.evernote.com/topic/25259-uploading-bulk-txt-files-to-a-notebook/

but none helped my issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Evernote export-import mechanism to do this, but you have to tweak the workflow a bit.

What you have to do is as follows.

Create a .enex file which is a standard evernote export file.  This  is just a standard xml that looks like this...  [image: Syntax of enex file]

The enex file you create can be generated programatically by writing a small program  in vbscript/any programming or scripting language that can read a folder and put file name in title tag and content inside content tag and save the resultant string as a .enex file.

Once this is done, you can use import function of evernote to import the enex file. Once you write the program, wihch may be an effort of less than 20 minutes, you can import hundreds of files within seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mac or PC desktop app, try dragging and dropping the .txt file to the notebook you want to save it to. This works for me.